# Cannot Implicitly Convert int to int[]

Tags: c#, casting, console-application

There are a few solutions out there, but none have worked for me. As far as my question I am building multiple arrays. Here are my variables and the code I am having an issue with:

```
static int      numOfEmployees;
static string[] nameArray;
static int[]    idArray, deptArray;
static double[] payArray, hoursArray;

static void InputEmployeeData()
{
    int      i;
    string[] words;

    numOfEmployees  = Int32.Parse(fileIn.ReadLine());
    idArray         = new int[numOfEmployees + 1];
    nameArray       = new string[numOfEmployees + 1];
    deptArray       = new int[numOfEmployees + 1];
    payArray        = new double[numOfEmployees + 1];
    hoursArray      = new double[numOfEmployees + 1];

    for (i = 1; i <= numOfEmployees; i++)
    { 
        words       = fileIn.ReadFields();
        idArray     = Int32.Parse(words[0]);
        nameArray   = words[1];
        deptArray   = Int32.Parse(words[2]);
        payArray    = Double.Parse(words[3]);
        hoursArray  = Double.Parse(words[4]);
    }
}
```

Under my for loop I am getting on each line either "Cannot implicitly convert type int to int[]. Or type double to double[].

I have tried casting which seems to fail.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? All an `int[]` is, is an array of `int`, able to hold more than one `int`.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being downvoted so heavily: it is clear what OP is trying to achieve, and there is no doubt that he made a good effort at making his code work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are trying to assign arrays instead of assigning their members:

```
idArray     = Int32.Parse(words[0]);
```

should be

```
idArray[i]  = Int32.Parse(words[0]);
```

and so on. Better yet, create `EmployeeData` class that has individual fields for `id`, `name`, `dept`, and so on, and use it in place of parallel arrays:

```
class EmployeeData {
    public int Id {get;}
    public string Name {get;}
    public int Dept {get;}
    public double Pay {get;}
    public double Hours {get;}
    public EmployeeData(int id, string name, int dept, double pay, double hours) {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Dept = dept;
        Pay = pay;
        Hours = hours;
    }
}
```

Now you can make an array or a list of `EmployeeData`, and create individual employees as you read their info:

```
var employee = new EmployeeData[numOfEmployees];
// Index i starts from 0, not from 1
for (i = 0; i < numOfEmployees; i++) { 
    words       = fileIn.ReadFields();
    var id = Int32.Parse(words[0]);
    var name = words[1];
    var dept = Int32.Parse(words[2]);
    var pay = Double.Parse(words[3]);
    var hours = Double.Parse(words[4]);
    employee[i] = new EmployeeData(id, name, dept, pay, hours);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to ASSIGN an int value to an int array. This leads to a type mismatch which leads to a compiler error.

What you really want to do is to index into the array and assign the int at the specified index.

```
idArray[i] = int.Parse(words[0]);
```